# How to use ifeq inside of a define in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to do an ifeq inside of a define within a Makefile, but I seem to be running into some errors, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  I have the following Makefile:

```
$(info ---- start ----)
ifeq ("X","Y")
$(info DOES not appear_1)
endif

define TESTDEF
ifeq ("X","Y")
$(info SHOULD not appear)
# $(error DEFINITELY SHOULD not error...)
endif
endef

$(eval $(call TESTDEF, 1,2,3))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
---- start ----
SHOULD not appear
Makefile:14: *** DEFINITELY SHOULD not error....  Stop.
```

Is there some trick that I'm missing?  Is it possible to do ifeq's inside define?  (note: this happens on both my native GNU 3.81 make, and on my mips uclibc cross-compiler)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you `call` this function, Make evaluates the definition, using whatever parameters you provide (irrelevant in this case). So if the definition includes something like `$(info ...)` or `$(error ...)`, *even in a comment*, Make will evaluate it and you'll see the result (see [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Contents.html); I've tested it in GNUMake 3.81).

To get the behavior you want, add a couple of dollar signs:

```
define TESTDEF
ifeq ("X","Y")
$$(info SHALL not appear)
# $$(info DEFINITELY SHALL not error...)
endif
endef

$(eval $(call TESTDEF))
```

Comment: Additionally, the `ifeq` is evaluated during the first pass. If `ifeq` references call variables like `$(1)` they're expanded during initial evaluation of `TESTDEF`, when they don't exist. Use `$(if ...)` instead. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions

Comment: made my day, simple & precise !!

Comment: @CraigRinger -- just looking at this.   If you do an `ifeq ($1,)` inside of the macro, the `$1` is not expanded until the `$(call` is expanded, and thus it is valid to use the `ifeq` inside of the define (though I wouldn't recommend that practice)...