# How define a makefile condition and reuse it in several build rules?

Tags: makefile, eval, variable-assignment, gnu-make

This could or not be a duplicate of [Makefile Variable Assignment Executes Early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999306/makefile-variable-assignment-executes-early)

Is it possible to define a condition and reuse it later?

```latex
MAIN_FILE_PATH := main

define copy_resulting_pdf=
if [[ -f "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}" ]] \
then \
    cp "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}" "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}.pdf"; \
else \
    $(error Error: The PDF ${MAIN_FILE_PATH} was not generated!); \
fi
endef

all:
    echo doing other things.
    $(copy_resulting_pdf)


other:
    echo doing more other things.
    $(copy_resulting_pdf)
```

When run this, make does not even start to build the `all` rule. It just throws out:

```
Makefile:14: *** Error: The PDF main was not generated!.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `$(error ...)` is a **text substitution** too. So any expansion of `$(copy_resulting_pdf)` also leads to the recursive expansion of all embedded variables and functions, including `$(error ...)`. Normally, `$(error ...)` is guarded by make conditionals (such as `ifeq`), or another substitutions (such as `$(if ...)`). But in your case it was "guarded" by shell conditional, which means nothing to make.

But the following works just as expected:

```
MAIN_FILE_PATH := main

define copy_resulting_pdf
    echo Printing results...
    if [[ -f "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}" ]]; then \
        printf 'Copying PDF...\n'; \
        cp "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}" "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}.pdf"; \
    else \
        printf "Error: The PDF \"${MAIN_FILE_PATH}\" was not generated!\n"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
endef

.PHONY: all other
all:
    @echo doing other things.
    @$(copy_resulting_pdf)

other:
    @echo doing more other things.
    @$(copy_resulting_pdf)
```

Note: you don't need eval and some fancy escapes here.

Answer (score 1):

Just one note to add: writing *bash* control structures in a recipe is a bit of a code smell IMHO. Things invariably look better is you replace them with *make* idioms.

Another smell here is when you lie to *make*: Your makefile does not say that the recipe for `all` creates `main.pdf` for instance.

```
MAIN_FILE_PATH := main

.PHONY: other_things
other_things:
    blah-dy-blah…

${MAIN_FILE_PATH}.pdf: | other_things
${MAIN_FILE_PATH}.pdf: ${MAIN_FILE_PATH}
    cp $< $@

.PHONY: all
all: ${MAIN_FILE_PATH}.pdf
    echo $@ Success
```

So what happens when you ask *make* to make `all`?

- `all`:

  - pre-requisite: *make* needs to build `main.pdf`

    - pre-requisite: *make* builds `other_things`

      - `blah-dy-blah…`runs
    - recipe: `main` is copied to `main.pdf`
  - recipe: `all Success` is printed

The existence of `main` is checked by *make* rather than *bash*.
One good characteristic of this is that you can easily add another recipe if you have a programmatic way of creating `main`.
Another is that the copy does not happen if `main.pdf` is already up-to-date.

Since you are no longer lying to *make*,
this makefile is parallel safe,
allowing you to use the `-j`*n* flag.
Hello performance.

Comment: Thanks for the patience explaining how everything should be done! This was great learning in makefiles for me.

Comment: That pipe thing you used can be explained here: [Order-only prerequisites not working correctly in GNU make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821611/order-only-prerequisites-not-working-correctly-in-gnu-make)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do it with this:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
MAIN_FILE_PATH := main

define copy_resulting_pdf=
echo Printing results...
eval "if [[ -f "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}" ]]; then \
    printf 'Coping PDF...\\n'; \
    cp "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}" "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}.pdf"; \
else \
    printf \"Error: The PDF "${MAIN_FILE_PATH}" was not generated!\\n\"; \
    exit 1; \
fi"
endef

all:
    echo doing other things.
    $(copy_resulting_pdf)
```

Running it:

```
echo doing other things.
doing other things.
echo Printing results...
Printing results...
eval "if [[ -f "main" ]]; then printf 'Coping PDF...\\n'; cp "main" "main.pdf"; else printf \"Error: The PDF "main" was not generated!\\n\"; exit 1; fi"
Error: The PDF main was not generated!
make: *** [setup/makefile.mk:17: all] Error 1
```

References:

1. [How can I use Bash syntax in Makefile targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets)
2. [How to use ifeq inside of a define in GNU Make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421848/how-to-use-ifeq-inside-of-a-define-in-gnu-make)

Comment: FYI, `$(error ...)` is considered as text substitution (which always returns an empty string). So **any expanding** `$(copy_resulting_pdf)` results in expanding `$(error ...)` too. Hence, the early error in your original code.